# NoReverseMatch at /polls/top/ Why can't I use <int:pk>?

Tags: python, django

I wrote in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Polls
def top(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':data})

def detail(request):
    data = Polls.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request,'detail.html',{'data':data})
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    url('detail/<int:pk>/', views.top,name='detail'),
]
```

in index.html

```
<main>
            {% for item in data %}
                            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
                            <a href="{% url 'detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL
</a>

            {% endfor %}
</main>
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Polls(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField()
```

When I access top method,
NoReverseMatch at /app/top/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/detail//'] error happens.I think I can access object's number by item.pk,but is it wrong?I rewrote `<a href="{% url 'detail' pk %}">` but same error happens.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: You are using the new `path()` syntax (new in Django 2.0) with the old `url()`. Make sure you are following the documentation for the correct version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

You have created app e.g. it's name is 'myapp' and you specified some url to your app

```
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp', app_name='myapp'))
```

So when you want to call some url which is inside this app you should call this like that

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL </a>
```